# python 3.x: bind arguments to given values

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, for a simple function `foo(x, y)` there are at least 3 ways that i know to bind the argument `y` to some value

```
# defining a nested function:
def foobar(x):
  return foo(x, y=yval)

# using lambda
foobar = lambda x: foo(x, y=yval)

# using functools
from functools import partial
foobar = partial(foo, y=yval)
```

while i am doubtful that the list above is exhaustive, i also wonder which one should i go with? are they all equivalent in terms of performance, safety and namespace handling? or are there extra overheads and caveats with each method? why should `functools` define `partial` when the other methods are already there?

Comment: `partial` doesn't really "bind" arguments to values. It defines a new function that wraps the old function, and "fills in" the argument value when it calls the old function.

Comment: @JoelCornett The same is true for all other options as well. It's pretty much the only way to do this without putting it into the builtin which represents functions.

Comment: @delnan: Yep. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they're not all equivalent -- in particular, a `lambda` cannot be pickled and a `functools.partial` can, IIRC, be pickled only in recent Python versions (I can't find which exact version in the docs; it doesn't work in 2.6, but it does in 3.1). Neither can functions defined inside of other functions (neither in 2.6 nor 3.1).

The reason for `partial`'s appearance in the library is that it gives you an explicit idiom to partially apply a function inline. A definition (`def`) cannot appear in the middle of an expression such as

```
map(partial(foo, y=yval), xs)
```

Also, from a definition or `lambda`, it's not immediately clear that partial application is what's going on, since you can put an arbitrary expression in a `lambda` and arbitrary statements in a definition.

I suggest you go with `partial` unless you have a reason not to use it.

[And indeed, the list is not exhaustive. The first alternative that comes to mind is a callable object:

```
class foobar:
    def __init__(self, yval):
        self.__yval = yval
    def __call__(self, x):
        return foo(x, self.__yval)
```

but those are heavy-weights for such a simple problem.]

Comment: Is it just `partial`, or any wrapped function that can't be pickled in previous versions?

Comment: @JoelCornett: `lambda` cannot be pickled in any version, neither can nested functions, I believe.